# Sitecore 9 Update 1 installation EXM Master DB Name

Tags: installation, sitecore-install-framework

I'm trying to install Sitecore 9 Update 1 and i'm getting the following error

[image]

i'm using the following script:

```
#define parameters 
$prefix = "S9U1Demo" 
$PSScriptRoot = "C:\Resourcefiles"
$XConnectCollectionService = "$prefix.xconnect" 
$sitecoreSiteName = "$prefix.Site" 
$SolrUrl = "https://localhost:8983/solr" 
$SolrRoot = "C:\Solr-6.6.2" 
$SolrService = "solr-6.6.2" 
$SqlServer = "CLDBHPMKJ\SQLEXPRESS" 
$SqlAdminUser = "Sitecore9" 
$SqlAdminPassword="test" 

#install client certificate for xconnect 
$certParams = @{ 
    Path = "$PSScriptRoot\xconnect-createcert.json" 
    CertificateName = "$prefix.xconnect_client" 
} 
Install-SitecoreConfiguration @certParams -Verbose 

#install solr cores for xdb 
$solrParams = @{ 
    Path = "$PSScriptRoot\xconnect-solr.json" 
    SolrUrl = $SolrUrl 
    SolrRoot = $SolrRoot 
    SolrService = $SolrService 
    CorePrefix = $prefix 
} 
Install-SitecoreConfiguration @solrParams 

#deploy xconnect instance 
$xconnectParams = @{ 
    Path = "$PSScriptRoot\xconnect-xp0.json" 
    Package = "$PSScriptRoot\Sitecore 9.0.1 rev. 171219 (OnPrem)_xp0xconnect.scwdp.zip"
    LicenseFile = "$PSScriptRoot\license.xml" 
    Sitename = $XConnectCollectionService 
    XConnectCert = $certParams.CertificateName 
    SqlDbPrefix = $prefix 
    SqlServer = $SqlServer 
    SqlAdminUser = $SqlAdminUser 
    SqlAdminPassword = $SqlAdminPassword 
    SolrCorePrefix = $prefix 
    SolrURL = $SolrUrl 
} 
Install-SitecoreConfiguration @xconnectParams 

#install solr cores for sitecore 
$solrParams = @{ 
    Path = "$PSScriptRoot\sitecore-solr.json" 
    SolrUrl = $SolrUrl 
    SolrRoot = $SolrRoot 
    SolrService = $SolrService 
    CorePrefix = $prefix 
} 
Install-SitecoreConfiguration @solrParams 

#install sitecore instance 
$xconnectHostName = "$prefix.xconnect" 
$sitecoreParams = @{ 
    Path = "$PSScriptRoot\sitecore-XP0.json" 
    Package = "$PSScriptRoot\Sitecore 9.0.1 rev. 171219 (OnPrem)_single.scwdp.zip"
    LicenseFile = "$PSScriptRoot\license.xml" 
    SqlDbPrefix = $prefix 
    SqlServer = $SqlServer 
    SqlAdminUser = $SqlAdminUser 
    SqlAdminPassword = $SqlAdminPassword 
    SolrCorePrefix = $prefix 
    SolrUrl = $SolrUrl 
    XConnectCert = $certParams.CertificateName 
    Sitename = $sitecoreSiteName 
    XConnectCollectionService = "https://$XConnectCollectionService" 
} 
Install-SitecoreConfiguration @sitecoreParams
```

Has anyone run in to this before?

Comment: Did you updated json files for 9.0.1? Installation script looks fine

Comment: I don't think i have, i can't seem to find them either. What download contains these files?

Comment: What are the changes required for json files?

Comment: I am also experiencing this error. I do have correct files using. I'm not sure what to do. [![enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/37R1x.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/37R1x.png)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This error appear because you don't have the right json configuration files

From https://dev.sitecore.net/Downloads/Sitecore_Experience_Platform/90/Sitecore_Experience_Platform_90_Update1.aspx

You need to get entire package for xp0

[image]

This package contains 3 zip files: (you already use : **Sitecore 9.0.1 rev. 171219 (OnPrem)_xp0xconnect.scwdp.zip** and  **Sitecore 9.0.1 rev. 171219 (OnPrem)_single.scwdp.zip** )

[image]

On XP0 configuration files are the configuration for 9.0.1 release. 
This config files are a little bit different than 9.0 release. For example it referrer EXM databases (exm.master and messaging)

[image]

Comment: Hi,
I really didn't get it. You just mentioned that " This config files are a little bit different than 9.0 release. For example it referrer EXM databases (exm.master and messaging)"
SO what are the changes that have to be made to those files?

Comment: he used json files for 9.0 in 9.0.1

Comment: You shouldn't be making these changes yourself download the new json files from the website!

Comment: Actually I downloaded the latest version as mentioned in the above answer. However, I am still getting the same issue. 
Any thoughts?

Comment: Hi,
The issue got resolved. as mentioned in the above mail, by mistake I have pointed to config files for 9.0 release. Once I pointed to 9.0.1 release, everything worked fine.
Thanks.